# Getting a particular value from ajax response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, jquery-masonry

I am using ajax with masonry

Ajax code: This ajax is used to get data from

```
$.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "some.php",
      dataType: "text",                 
      success: function(data) { 
        if (data && data.length > 0) {       
          $items = $(data); 
          $grid.append( $items )
          .masonry('appended', $items);
          $(this).find(".loading").hide();
        }
      }
```

Php Part: This is just a small or sufficient part of php file to understand the problem

```
$b= "sv";
echo "asjdgsajd";
echo "a";
echo $b;
```

now i am getting everything correctly but i want to use say value of $b for setting a attribute value and also other values as content but how can i particularly get value of $b?
Thankyou

Comment: Can you post a full example of your AJAX response? And why not use JSON instead?

Comment: sv
asjdgsajd
a
after using break after every echo @Machavity

Comment: Using JSON would make this much easier. Is there a reason you use dataType:"text"

Comment: nope not as such a paticular reason then how to do iit with jason @some-non-descript-user

Answer (score 4):

Change the `dataType` to `json`.

```
$.ajax({
      type: "get",
      url: "some.php",
      dataType: "json",                 
      success: function(data) { 
        //data will hold an object with your response data, no need to parse
        console.log('Do whatever you want with ' + data.b + '.');
      }
```

In `some.php` do the following:

```
$response =array(
    'b' => "sv",
    'a' => "asjdgsajd",
    'c' => "a"
);
echo json_encode($response);
echo $b;
```

The items of the associative array will end up as properties of a javascript object, that you can use in your `success` callback (or `done` function as `success` is deprecated).

Comment: if i do not change the datatype from text because i cannot convert whole of the code to json data as there is lot of data in actual file then? @some-non-descript-user

Comment: Well you have to make "b" discernable somehow. You could put it in special parantheses or something and do some messy regex work to pull it out of the text stream, then. But I'd really advice to rather do it in a clean way.

Comment: Maybe you could separate the requests where you need to get text only from the ones that you need clean values from and fetch them with different ajax calls?

Answer (score 2):

Try using json and change your php to send the json response that way you can send more content and access them on client side as you need it.

PHP Script :

```
$outArr=array("b"=>"sv","content1"=>"asjdgsajd","content2"=>"a");
$jsonResponse=json_encode($outArr);
echo $jsonResponse;
```

In AJAX function you can access your data like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "get",
  url: "some.php",
  dataType: "text",                 
  success: function(data) { 
    if (data && data.length > 0) {       
      data=$.parseJSON( data ); //parse response string
      b=data.b;//value of b
      content1=data.content1;//value of content1
      $("#exampleDiv").attr("id",b).html(content1); //set the attribute and content here for an example div
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: can you do your suggested edit in above ajax code only @Amit